# chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow not work, but chrome.identity.getAuthToken working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow will result in 400: redirect_uri_mismatch.
But chrome.identity.getAuthToken is success.
Also, when I tried the client IDs of other projects, chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow also worked properly.
The difference is that OAuth is being reviewed.
What is the cause?

```js
const manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();
const scopes = manifest.oauth2.scopes;
const clientId = manifest.oauth2.client_id;

const url = new URL('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth');
url.searchParams.append('client_id', clientId);
url.searchParams.append('redirect_uri', chrome.identity.getRedirectURL('auth'));
url.searchParams.append('response_type', 'code token');
url.searchParams.append('scope', scopes.join(' '));
url.searchParams.append('access_type', 'offline');
const email = localStorage.getItem('email');
if (email) {
  url.searchParams.append('login_hint', email);
}

chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({ url: url.href, interactive: true }, (redirectURL) => console.log(redirectURL));
```

Comment: `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow` doesn't work for Google accounts in Chrome. They have `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
Using the web client id.